# Printing Arabic characters adds small visual differences and inserts additional unicode characters

Tags: unicode, printing, arabic, postscript

So I printing this Arabic text ("First Party Second Party"):
لطرف الأول الطرف الثانى

Sometimes it prints like this: ﻟطرف اﻷول اﻟطرف اﻟﺛﺎﻧﻰ

The 'original' text converted to unicode reads:
\u0644\u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0648\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u062b\u0627\u0646\u0649

The data in the print job reads:
\ufedf\u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0627\ufef7\u0648\u0644 \u0627\ufedf\u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0627\ufedf\ufe9b\ufe8e\ufee7\ufef0

So why is this happening? I can search through the print job data and act upon certain words, but cannot seem to wrap my head around why the print data changes for Arabic languages.

There are also small differences visually detectable:
[image: Visually detectable differences]
Thank you all!

Comment: Just my guess but your printer/printer driver automatically converts it because it is unable to print the original text. This isn't related to programming, unless you're using some code to send this text to your printer, and in that case please provide the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typsetting for Arabic is different than Roman scripts, particularly in the way it handles ligatures and justification. To put this in context, consider English, which has a few ligatures for typesetting combinations such as ff, fi and ffi which are all typically rendered as single character in the output.

Below are three characters ffi, rendered as a single ligature character (\uFB03).

[image: Three characters ffi rendered as a single character ligature.]

Here's an article about ligatures in general.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

For justification, Roman scripts typically insert spaces or hyphens (as well as kerning). With Arabic, it is considered more pleasing to stretch the width of the strokes using "kashidas", extra characters that cause the appearance of stretching.

In general, the number Unicode characters used in typeset text may be more or less than than the original text.

Here a couple of references for Arabic, if you are interested.

https://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb27-2/tb87benatia.pdf

https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-arabic-calligraphy-kashida-tajim-and-tashkil--cms-23240

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for this post and the very interesting references. This is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello Joel, seeing you've got some experience with this, do you also have experience with putting this into a regular expression?

Comment: Not sure what you want reg expressions to do for you. Sounds like that is probably a separate question.  Also, Did I answer your question above? If so, accept the answer (not same as upvoting). If not, clarify your question what still needs to be answered. Thx

Comment: Did you figure out your RegEx question? Not sure what you were trying to do.

Comment: No, not yet. Im trying to capture the words in the first phrase, but it sometimes mismatches because the printer driver puts in these characters.

Comment: So you are looking for a regular expression that will will identify each word in the print data, then use that that to determine what the original words are (prior to formatting)? Something along those lines?